# Visual Studio Code - Cannot create process, Error Code 5

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code on a new Computer, but when I try to debug or launch a terminal, I get the following error:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 5).
Verbose:    onDidChangeNotification @   notificationsAlerts.ts:40
```

I'm using Windows Version 10.0.19042.1202 and VS Code 1.60.1

Any idea about what can cause that trouble?
Cannot find anything related to error code 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it.
There was a deny permission on the file that runs PowerShell. So, i've checked and deleted all deny permissions on the file C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe and VS Code started working.

I've notice the trouble, because I've just tried to execute PowerShell from outside of Visual Studio Code, and it didn't open (Without any error).

Answer (score 1):

While I should probably be commenting this, I don't have enough reputation so here it is:

I found a related thread/issue in the VS Code github [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112202). Long story short, try installing the latest version of VS Code. If you have confirmed that you are running the latest version, try installing the latest preview release in [insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) (this seemed to solve the issue in github).

Comment: Thanks.. I've just tried with the insiders version, but I still get the error.. Also tried launch VS Code as Admin.. but the error is still there. I don't know what else to do

Comment: Honestly, I'm stumped now. At least the VS Code team appears to be aware of the issue... hopefully.